# Mobile browsers horizontal scrollable inside vertical scrollable

Tags: html, css, mobile

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xU5NZ/1/) showing the issue.

Basically, I have a div inside a div. Both need scrolling, but one needs horizontal scrolling (the outer one), the other one needs vertical scrolling (the inner one). On a PC this works fine, but on mobile browsers (checked stock Android and mobile Chrome), I can only scroll (slide) horizontally, but not vertically.

Any clues? Code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="firstContainer">
        <div class="secondContainer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.firstContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 130%;
    background: #808080;
    overflow: auto;
}

.secondContainer {
    height: 80%;
    width: 130%;
    background: #d0d0d0;
    border: 15px solid black;
}
```

Comment: On Safari, you sometimes need to use two-fingers to scroll inside an element. One workaround is to use a library such as iScroll: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5